# socat: Show incoming connections

Tags: networking, unix, tcp, socat

I am slightly going mad. Even if I call socat like this:

```
socat -vvvv tcp4-listen:9000 tcp4-listen:9001
```

it works perfectly, but doesn't inform me about incoming TCP connections! Is there an additional verbosity option that makes socat show this information, something like

```
Connection from XYZ
```

Can't be such a special function, or can it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By old habit I am just used to grouping arguments together like `-dddd` for more verbose debugging, but when I actually tried what the manpage said (`-d -d`) it worked just fine. For logging connections, just do:

```
socat -d -d tcp4-listen:9000 tcp4-listen:9001
```

Comment: ps; in your example the connection isn't "established" until something has connected to both port 9000 and 9001, so the output is printed upon both parties being connected. Just so you don't test only connections to one port and think it fails because it doesn't print anything. :P

Comment: In this case I am interested in connections to both sides separately (or in fact only the lefthand listen part). Thanks for your answer, I'll accept this if nobody can provide a better solution (no offense, but this doesn't quite serve my use case).

Comment: I gave it some more thought and came up with a very simple solution, so I replaced my old suggestion. If someone is interested they can look at the old edits. :P Hope this is good enough for your use case!

Comment: ... but socat -d -d is a bit too wordy.  It would be nice to have an option to log only one line per connection.